# Embeded Podcast Player - need it to auto Start when the user lands on the page (instead of having to hit the play button)

Tags: html, web, media-player, html5-audio

https://www.buzzsprout.com/510487.js?container_id=buzzsprout-large-player-510487&player=large'>

Please forgive me as I am not savvy on HTML but is there a way to paste this code into my website but have it start playing the top track when the user hits the page? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `audio` tag of html5, you can use, "autoplay" attribute.